# Excel VBA macro does not work as intented

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write (*actually modify :)*) a macro to do the following;

1. Filter data based on each value in a particular column (In this case 1 st column)
2. Copy/populate filtered data (In this to a array)
3. Paste in to a specific workbook's specific worksheet (I need to paste this filtered data in to a file which is available on my Hard drive with the same name that i used to filter data)
4. Save the file and close the file.

The macro is not working as intended;
- Sometime macro is run to end but data has not populated to files.
- Sometime data populated to some files but not to all files.

Below is my code (*modified, original got from Stack Overflow*). Thanks!

```
Sub parse_data()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer
    Dim Name As String
    Dim SheetName As String

    ' Getting the worksheet name which filtered data to be pasted.
    SheetName = InputBox("Please enter the name of experiment")

    'The column number of Splitting data based on
    vcol = 1

    'The base sheet name
    Set ws = Sheets("Total")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row

    'Range of table headings
    title = "A1:K1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique"

    For i = 2 To lr

        On Error Resume Next

        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then
            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    ws.Columns(icol).Clear

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
            'Open data sheets which filtered data to be copied
            Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\\Findings\" & myarr(i) & ".xlsm")
            Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
            ActiveWorkbook.LockServerFile
        End If
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(SheetName).Range("A1")
        Sheets(SheetName).Columns.AutoFit

        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Next
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: Modify/Write/Copy... it's all the same in programming!  Obviously the key is figuring out where the problem lies.  You can use **[F8]** to **step through the code** line by line, checking the values of the variables etc as you go to determine where the problem lies.  Here is more [**VBA Debugging**](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) advice.  Also, it's important that any code included in your question is a **[mcve]**.  (See also **[help/on-topic]**.)

Comment: 'not copulated'? ;)

Comment: Hi  ashleedawg,  Thanks for the advice. I already tried what you suggested, but could not figure out where the problem is. When i tried with the little amount of data it works fine. But when i tried it with around 3000 records, the problem occurred. Are their any maximum number of records that can be used with arrays?

Comment: The first step is to get rid of `On Error Resume Next`. That should almost never be used because it's saying "ignore all errors" (which is bound to cause problems).  Also, it is located within a  loop.  (Notice how it's easier to see that now that the code is properly indented.)  I'd suggest fixing the things mentioned by myself and others here and then try **stepping through the code** again, as well as the other troubleshooting tips in the links

Comment: I don't understand what your are about to achive but I can give some hints: 1. I'd review `If Not Evaluate` block because you copy even if you do not open a new file. Your copied data may be there somewhere else. The same applies for `ActiveWorkbook`: there is always an `ActiveWorkbook`, but it may be other than intended. 2. `.End(xlUp)` can be cheating when calling from within a sheet with empty cells. You'd better find the 1st empty row below data and count. 3. Consider using `range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy` when copying filtered cells.

Comment: Hi, acserno, I Have two files named;

1. Local Admin (Including: PC names, Admin Account Name, and Physical location)
2. Software (Including: Software name, Physical Location)
Further, I have several excel files for each physical location (EX; New York, Paris), within each these files there are worksheets named, “Local Admin "and “Software ”.
When I run the Macro on Local Admin file, data should be filtered according to their physical location and copied in to respective location files. 
Likewise, data within the software file should be filtered and populated to respective files.

Comment: @ashleedawg has given you excellent advice, I hope you've followed it and will report back. We are limited in what we can do, not knowing anything of your set up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to fix the volatility of the files/sheets used:

```
Option Explicit
dim fout as workbook
dim sout as worksheet
on error goto 0
For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
    ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
    If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then
        'Open data sheets which filtered data to be copied
        set fout=Workbooks.Open ("C:\Users\\Findings\" & myarr(i) & ".xlsm")
        if fout is nothing then goto errorhandler
        set sout=fout.Worksheets(SheetName)
        if sout is nothing then goto errorhandler
        fout.LockServerFile
        if err.number <>0 then goto errorhandler
        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy sout.Range("A1")
        sout.Columns.AutoFit

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        fout.Close true            ' save & close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        set fout=nothing
        set sout=nothing
    End If
Next
```